# New to Java and Programming: Setting up a development environment on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: java, development-environment, osx-yosemite

I am a student taking an introduction to programming class and Java is the language we are learning. Does anyone have any pointers or recommendations on how to set up a development environment for Mac OS X Yosemite? I configured Terminal to run the latest version of Java in Terminal (http://gist.github.com/johan/10590467)
I would appreciate any other pointers and advice from the programming community. Thanks very much!

Update: 20/03/2015 00:38
I realized that this question might be better for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/. My apologies. I am still a bit new at using these resources.

Comment: I do all my Java development on a Mac, but I run it through Ubuntu on VirtualBox. Seems safer to keep Java away from OS X, and it also allows you to have different environments for different projects (different Java versions for example) easily.

Comment: Ok thanks Thilo! I have been looking into Ubuntu as well. Still very new to all of this but I will continue to research your suggestion.

Comment: I don't think there's any concern with installing a JDK on a Mac. I've used my Mac for Java development for a number of years. OS X is a great platform for Java development - you've got the *nix based OS under the covers and can dip into Terminal when needed, you've got all the main IDEs to chose from, and the stability of OS X ... it's always surprised me how many developers you see at conferences like JavaOne with their MacBooks and MacBook Pros... if laptops at a conference is any indication I'd guess that the Mac is the dominant OS for Java development :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using an IDE in your class, like Eclipse or Netbeans? There are Mac version of both, and both run great on the Mac. Otherwise I would stick to setting up a similar development environment as close as you can get to what you are using in class so you don't have to work out other platform/tool issues and differences.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks. Someone in my class did mention Eclipse. I'll get it set up. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You've probably already found the download page, but if not, here you go: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=macosx